# How to scrap ACS publications website? (avoid http 403 error)

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests, http-status-code-403

I have been trying to create a scrapper with Python requests package to scrape some information from ACS publication website (https://pubs.acs.org/).

I have tried several different User-Agent strings in headers, all gave me the same 403 error.

I read the robots.txt at ACS website and I konw that they do not allow automatic web scrappers. And they might have used some anti-scrap techniques in their website. I wish to use the scrapper that I tried to create for small-scale information scrapping and low frequency (several times per day). So I thought it might be OK?

Any advice how to bypass the ACS website anti-scrapping? Or general advice on how to simulate scrapping as a real browser?

And here is my code:

```
import requests
headers = {
"User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"
}
r = requests.get("https://pubs.acs.org", headers=headers)
r.raise_for_status()
```

Return:
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://pubs.acs.org/.

Answer (score 0):

You can try just copying the headers that your browser sends, since you know that got an ok response:

[image: http request headers]

I got this from having the network tab open on the dev tools of chrome. It will be the first request that pops up and the request and response headers will be found there.

And after that, if you want, you can mock this request in postman or even in your app or whatever, and see what header fields are mandatory to get an ok response.

Good luck and try not to get into trouble.